# Verificar o tipo de input

Tags: python-3.x, input

Boas pessoal!
Preciso de fazer uma verificação de input para um trabalho e não estou a conseguir fazer isto como deve de ser.
Isto é o que eu tenho até agr:

```
def verificação1():
     while True:
        try:
            quantidade=int(input("Insira a quantidade: "))
            quantidade=str(quantidade)
            print("Insira um produto válido.")
            continue
        except:
            break
```

O objectivo deste pedaço de código é verificar que a quantidade é mesmo um número inteiro e não uma string ou float por exemplo. Mas quando corro isto não parece funcionar...

Answer (score -1):

Apesar de dar eu colocaria a declaração da `quantidade` fora do `try` por uma questão de contexto, o que nós queremos tentar (`try`) é apenas tranformar a quantidade para inteiro. Podes fazer com recursividade:

```
def verificação1():
    quantidade=input("Insira a quantidade: ")
    try: 
        return int(quantidade) 
    except ValueError:
        print("Insira um produto válido.")
        return verificação1()
print('A quantidade é {}'.format(verificação1()))
```

Ou, fazendo com o ciclo `while` como tens na pergunta:

```
def verificação1():
    while True:
        quantidade=input("Insira a quantidade: ")
        try:
            return int(quantidade)
        except Exception as err:
            print("Insira um produto válido.")
print('A quantidade é {}'.format(verificação1()))
```

Em ambos os exemplos para transformar em `str`, podes, fora da função:

```
str(verificação1())
```

Se bem que usando algum destes exemplos acho desnecessário.

Não percebi bem se faz parte da pergunta, mas o saber não ocupa espaço. Para saber se uma variável é de um tipo específico pode:

```
hey = 'heya' # todos sabemos que é uma string
isinstance(hey, float) # False
isinstance(hey, str) # True
```